# Inject string to const char* message in custom logger printf-style function

Tags: c++, arduino-esp32, chararray, printf-debugging

I have a debugger class which implements a **printf() c style** method.
It looks like this:

```
#define NO_DEBUG 0
#define NO_PREFIX 1
#define DEBUG_INFO 2
#define DEBUG_SUCCESS 3
#define DEBUG_WARN 4
#define DEBUG_ERROR 5
#define MAX_DEBUG_LEVEL 5


#define DEBUG_INFO_PREFIX "[INFO] "
#define DEBUG_SUCCESS_PREFIX "[SUCCESS] "
#define DEBUG_WARN_PREFIX "[WARN] "
#define DEBUG_ERROR_PREFIX "[ERROR] "

/*
*   Printing debug information to Serial in c printf style
*   If the level is higher then the global debug level or
*   the level is NO_DEBUG ( see debug.h ) then the message is not printed.
*/
void DebugSystem::print(byte level, const char *message, ...){
    if( level > debugLevel || level == NO_DEBUG ){ return; }
    char buffer[PRINT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    printPrefix(level);
    va_list  args;
    va_start (args, message);
        vsprintf (buffer, message, args);
        Serial.print(buffer);
    va_end (args);
}
```

It is used like this:

```
int count = 0;
debug.print(DEBUG_INFO,"Test message: %s,%d\n","testMSG",count);
debug.print(DEBUG_SUCCESS,"Test message: %s,%d\n","testMSG",count);
debug.print(DEBUG_WARN,"Test message: %s,%d\n","testMSG",count);
debug.print(DEBUG_ERROR,"Test message: %s,%d\n","testMSG",count);
```

It is working very well. Now i want to add a prefix
before the message which i have implemented like this:

```
/*
*   Printing a prefix before the message based on it's level.
*   Levels:
*    - INFO prefix --> [INFO] 
*    - WARN prefix --> [WARN] 
*    - ERROR prefix --> [ERROR] 
*    - SUCCESS prefix --> [SUCCESS] 
*/ 
void DebugSystem::printPrefix(byte level){
    if( !levelPrefix || level == NO_PREFIX ){ return; }
    const char* prefix = level == DEBUG_ERROR ? DEBUG_ERROR_PREFIX
        : level == DEBUG_WARN    ? DEBUG_WARN_PREFIX
        : level == DEBUG_SUCCESS ? DEBUG_SUCCESS_PREFIX
        : DEBUG_INFO_PREFIX;
    Serial.print(prefix);
}
```

But i have a small problem.
If the user want's to print \n at the beginning of the message, the output will be ill formatted.

*Here is an example:*

```
debug.print(DEBUG_INFO,"Test message: %s\n","TEST");
debug.print(DEBUG_INFO,"\nTest message: %s\n","TEST");
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Test message: TEST
[INFO]
      Test message: TEST
```

For this to work properly i have two solutions in mind
Either check the first param ( i don't know how ) and if it is a new line '\n' character i remove it and print it before the prefix or i have to inject my prefix after the first \n character into the message.

I'm using Arduino framework to do all of this but i can't think of an elegant solution.

Expected output of this test message would be:

```
[INFO] Test message: TEST

[INFO] Test message: TEST
```

Ofc the problem is not just with the \n but any format character in the string. I need a robust solution, some regex or something to detect if there is a formatter character in the beginning of the arguments, remove and print it before the prefix.

Comment: This isn't C code, please don't tag as such.

Comment: I tagged it as C++ and arduino

Comment: It got tagged as C on creation somehow, maybe automatically, but that's been removed.

Comment: Really interesting

Comment: @Dr.Random, you did tag c but was removed by @tadman. It is actually better to use `Arduino-c++` tag for question like this than the generic `c++` tag.

Answer (score 0):

And there might be comments with several `\n` somewhere in the text.

**You might repeat the prefix after every `\n` except for the trailing one at the end.
And if there no ending `\n` add a `\n`.**

Of course there often is a misconception that lines start with `\n`; one idea that should not be "repaired" - unnecessarily accepting that.

There might be more that one debug printf, meant to be printed as one text block. That you cannot determine:

```
if (i++ % 10 == 0) printf("\n...
printf
```

Comment: Yeah but for example i usually do a \n only if i want a new line. If this function will put a prefix before every \n the console would have prefixes before empty lines.

Comment: At the start `\n` might be discarded and at the end `\n`  added if is not there. Other `\n`s might be replaced with `\n`+prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This not directly answer your question. But why reinvent the wheel when you could enable the ESP32 logging system from Arduino IDE Tools -> Core Debug Level?

[image]

And then you could use the ESP logging system as

```cpp
log_i( "I'm using the ESP logging system");
```

I would suggest you take a look at the [esp32-hal-log.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-log.h) of the ESP32-Arduino Core and read more about [esp-idf logging system](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/log.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I aware the existence of the logging system. I wanted to create my own because i do much more in my own class. It can log messages to the file system and much more. I did not stated what IDE iam using but i use PlatformIO instead of the Arduino IDE.

Comment: It works on PlatformIO too.